# The default Content-Security-Policy is currently overridden using the hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP issue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

After upgrading Jenkins to v2.222.1 we got the below warning message

```
The default Content-Security-Policy is currently overridden using the hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP system property, which is a potential security issue when browsing untrusted files. As an alternative, you can set up a Resource Root URL that Jenkins will use to serve some static files without adding Content-Security-Policy headers.
```

we don't want to have separate source to serve static content meanwhile this warning has to be addressed, pleased provide your suggestions..

Answer (score 1):

By default the CSS content will not be displayed when you publish any report using HTML Publisher plugin. Jenkins blocks the CSS based on CSP(Content Security Policy).

Ref: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/security/configuring-content-security-policy/

To enable CSS content: `Manage Jenkins -> Script Console` and execute `System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "")`

When the CSS is enabled you get the following warning `The default Content-Security-Policy is currently overridden using the hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP system property, which is a potential security issue when browsing untrusted files.`

To disable it just restart the Jenkins Server. The CSP will be again set to default.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me.
Thanks!
It seems though, like there should be a more permanent solution to this issue, since Jenkins now complains about "potential security issue when browsing untrusted files".

Answer (score 0):

When requesting .css or .js, the following message may occur `(blocked:csp)`.

```
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-Epaif2cHkSx/K62AHKClT5geuHQeilAdJVvUuNPdcuw='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

In that case, you should deal with it like this. Temporarily relaxing Content Security Policy. Go to `Manage Jenkins -> Script Console` and type into console the following commands:

```
System.clearProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP");
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts; default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ; font-src * data: ");
```